# selector never works on parsley 3.0 framework, so command never gets called

Tags: apache-flex, command, parsley

I am trying to use selector(which  to filter  event when command Object recevind the event, but never get's called!! help here my pieces of code:
Inmy context file:

```
    <MapCommand type="com.pz.events.FolderEvent" selector="folderDelete">
        <Command type="com.pz.command.DeleteFolderCommand"/>
    </MapCommand>
```

dipatching event code pieces:

```
    dispatchEvent(new FolderEvent(FolderEvent.FOLDER_DELETED,targetRoot.selectedItem));
```

MetaTag:

```
[Event(name="folderDelete",type="com.pz.events.FolderEvent")]
[ManagedEvents("folderCreate,folderDelete,folderOpen,folderClose,folderRelocate")]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably lies in you configuration file. The `type` attribute of `MapCommand` tag is not a message type, but a command type. For messages `messageType` attribute is used.

So your MXML code should look like this:

```mxml
<MapCommand messageType="com.pz.events.FolderEvent" selector="folderDelete">
    <Command type="com.pz.command.DeleteFolderCommand"/>
</MapCommand>
```

Or this:

```mxml
<MapCommand type="com.pz.command.DeleteFolderCommand" messageType="com.pz.events.FolderEvent" selector="folderDelete"/>
```